# Get the GPS Logger values into Sqlite in Android

Tags: android

This is my GPSLoggerservice code:

```
package com.mygps.android;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import com.mygps.android.AppSettings;
import com.mygps.android.AppLog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Environment;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class GPSLoggerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // this is a hack and need to be changed, here the offset is the length of

    // the tag XML "</Document></kml",

    // we minus this offset from the end of the file and write the next

    // Placemark entry.

    private static final int KML_INSERT_OFFSET = 17;



    private static final int gpsMinTime = 500;

    private static final int gpsMinDistance = 0;

    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;

    private static final int GEOCODER_MAX_RESULTS = 5;



    TextView abc;

    TextView abcd; 



    private LocationManager manager = null;

    private double latitude = 0.0;

    private double longitude = 0.0;

    private double altitude = 0.0;

    private Timer monitoringTimer = null;



    public GPSLoggerService() {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.GPSLoggerService().");

    }



    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onBind().");



        return null;

    }



    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onCreate().");



        super.onCreate();

    }



    @Override

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onStart().");



        startLoggingService();

        startMonitoringTimer();



        super.onStart(intent, startId);

    }



    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onStartCommand().");



        startLoggingService();

        startMonitoringTimer();



        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }



    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onLocationChanged().");



        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        altitude = location.getAltitude();

    }



    @Override

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onProviderDisabled().");

    }



    @Override

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onProviderEnabled().");

    }



    @Override

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        AppLog.logString("GPSLoggerService.onStatusChanged().");

    }



    private void startLoggingService() {

        if (manager == null) {

            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        }



        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();



        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);

        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);



        final String bestProvider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);



        if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0) {

            manager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, gpsMinTime,

                    gpsMinDistance, this);

        } else {

            final List<String> providers = manager.getProviders(true);



            for (final String provider : providers) {

                manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, gpsMinTime,

                        gpsMinDistance, this);

            }

        }

    }



    private void stopLoggingService() {

        stopSelf();

    }



    private void startMonitoringTimer() {

        monitoringTimer = new Timer();



        monitoringTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                if (longitude != 0.0 && latitude != 0.0) {

                    monitoringTimer.cancel();

                    monitoringTimer = null;



                    manager.removeUpdates(GPSLoggerService.this);



                    saveCoordinates(latitude, longitude, altitude,

                            getLocationName(latitude, longitude));

                    stopLoggingService();

                }

            }

        }, GPSLoggerService.TIMER_DELAY, GPSLoggerService.TIMER_DELAY);

    }



    private String getLocationName(double latitude, double longiture) {

        String name = "";

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);



        try {

            List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,

                    longiture, GPSLoggerService.GEOCODER_MAX_RESULTS);



            name = address.get(0).toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



        return name;

    }



    private void saveCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude,

            double altitude, String name) {

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),

                "GPSLogger");

        boolean isNew = false;



        if (!folder.exists()) {

            folder.mkdirs();



            isNew = true;

        }



        try {

            File kmlFile = new File(folder.getPath(),

                    AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));



            if (!kmlFile.exists()) {

                kmlFile.createNewFile();



                isNew = true;

            }



            if (isNew) {

                FileOutputStream initialWriter = new FileOutputStream(kmlFile,

                        true);



                String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"

                        + "<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">"

                        + "<Document>" + "</Document>" + "</kml>";



                initialWriter.write(xml.getBytes());

                initialWriter.flush();

                initialWriter.close();

            }



            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(

                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

            String dateString = sdf.format(new Date());



            String placemark = "<Placemark>" + "<name>" + name + "</name>"

                    + "<description>"

                    + "Created by GPSLogger sample application"

                    + "</description>" + "<TimeStamp>" + "<when>" + dateString

                    + "</when>" + "</TimeStamp>" + "<Point>" + "<coordinates>"

                    + String.valueOf(longitude) + ","

                    + String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(altitude)

                    + "</coordinates>" + "</Point>" + "</Placemark>"

                    + "</Document>" + "</kml>";





            String a = String.valueOf(longitude);

            String b = String.valueOf(latitude);



//          abc   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);

//          abcd  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longi);

//          

//          abc.setText(a);

//          abcd.setText(b);



        //  Toast.makeText(this, "a=" + a + "b=" + b , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AppLog.logString("abcdef" + a );

            //Log.i("Longi", a);


            RandomAccessFile fileAccess = new RandomAccessFile(kmlFile, "rw");
            FileLock lock = fileAccess.getChannel().lock();

            fileAccess.seek((kmlFile.length() - GPSLoggerService.KML_INSERT_OFFSET));

            fileAccess.write(placemark.getBytes());
            lock.release();

            fileAccess.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private TextView findViewById(int lat) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

}
```

The output i get in DDMS  data/data/com.xyz.abc is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<int name="loggingInterval" value="15" />
<string name="logFile">GPSLog.2011-12-28 15:38:05.kml</string>
<boolean name="isServiceRunning" value="true" />
</map>
```

How can i read this value and get the data

Comment: What do you mean by "this value"? and which "data"?

Comment: Any problem? If yes then provide logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your saving an xml document (an empty KML file) on the file system and then saving your coordinates in an xml-formatted string and then inserting that into the kml document. Finally, you then have the filename saved in another xml document. If you want to go this way then you need to read your kml file (GPSLog.2011-12-28 15:38:05.kml) and parse it so that you can extract the coordinates and any other data you've written there.
However, if you want to use SqlLite, you can create a table with separate fields to hold the coordinates and other pieces of data, or you can simply store your 'placemark' string in the database (with an appropriate _id key so that you can retrieve the data correctly) and then parse it into a GeoPoint object or your own extended object, if you have more data to store.
Personally, I use separate columns for latitude, longitude, altitude, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I too was looking for the same solution. i just need to get 2 values latitude and longitude from location manager and add that to my sqlite DB. I also need to update the GEOLogger data based on Time interval. Any sample code link will be a great help for me.

Comment: Here's a link to getting the Sqllite database in operation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402948/android-database/4403142#4403142